# Laravel elixir and autoprefixer

Tags: laravel, gulp, gulp-sass, laravel-elixir, autoprefixer

So I saw that elixir doesn't automatically use autoprefixer. This is how my gulp file looks:

```
var Elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var gulp = require('gulp');

Elixir.config.sourcemaps = false;

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('resources/sass/app.scss')
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css/app.css'));
});

Elixir(function(mix) {

    // Copy bootstrap.min.js to node vendor directory until it becomes a node module
    mix.copy('public/vendor/bootstrap-4', 'node_modules/bootstrap-4');

    // Combine all vendor scripts
    mix.scripts([
        'bootstrap-4/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        'vue/dist/vue.min.js'
    ], 'public/js/vendor.js', 'node_modules');

    // Combine all files into one single CSS file
    mix.task('sass', 'resources/sass/**/*.scss');

    // Get rid of cached version
    mix.version([
        'public/js/vendor.js',
        'public/css/app.css'
    ]);

});
```

But it's not issuing autoprefixer still. I get no gulp errors. And when I run `gulp watch`, it doesn't update whenever I update a .scss file. All my sass files are located under resources/sass

Thanks for any help!

I even tried:

```
new Task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('resources/sass/app.scss')
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css/app.css'));
})
.watch('resources/sass/**/*.scss');
```

Comment: Since Bootstrap 4 already has compiled CSS, why not just include that? Otherwise, there's a `mix.sass()` function you could use instead of creating a new task. Laravel Elixir automatically uses `autoprefixer` unless you disable it as well. See the following `Gulpfile.js` example: https://gist.github.com/divspace/3f952754581babb21c5b

Comment: I love when the Laravel docs leave us alone. There's no doc whatsoever on Autoprefixer, but I've asked for that in [#372](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/372)

Answer (score 10):

Although [currently](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/372) [undocumented](http://laravel.com/docs/master/elixir), Laravel's Elixir indeed runs your CSS through Autoprefixer, with it's mostly default settings, as found in the package's [Config.js](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/blob/master/Config.js):

```
{
    ...
    css: {
        autoprefix: {
            enabled: true,

            options:  {
                browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
                cascade: false
            }
        },
    }
}
```

To customize that configuration, you should use the following:

```
elixir.config.css.autoprefix = {
    enabled: true, //default, this is only here so you know how to disable
    options: {
        cascade: true,
        browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 1%']
    }
};

elixir(function(mix) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 5):

use this configurations

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
config.css.autoprefix.options.browsers =  ['last 15 versions'] ;

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('index.scss');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Your `gruntfile.js` should look like this:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {
  mix
    .copy('./public/vendor/bootstrap-4', './node_modules/bootstrap-4')
    .sass('app.scss')
    .scripts([
      './node_modules/bootstrap-4/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
      './node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js'
    ], './public/js/app.js')
    .version([
      'css/app.js',
      'js/app.css'
    ]);
});
```

Your `resources/assets/sass/app.scss` file should look like this:

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-4/scss/bootstrap";
```

You'll now have a directory structure like this:

```
public/build/css/app-**********.css
public/build/css/app.css.map
public/build/js/app-**********.js
public/build/js/app.js.map
public/css/app.css
public/css/app.map
public/js/app.js
public/js/app.map.js
```

The asterisks will be `[a-z0-9]{10}` but you'll load them by calling `{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}` and `{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}`.

Comment: are you answering the question or trying to teach the guy correct markup?